# When did Leia drop the "princess"

Tags: star-wars, princess-leia

I don't think I have ever heard Lea refer to herself as a "princess" however that was how people refereed to her in the original trilogy.

I guess that she officially lost the title when Alderan was reduced to a heap of smoldering rubble.

However in *The Empire Strikes Back* Han is happy to tease her about it. So it can't be that sore a point at that point in time.

In *The Force Awakens* we have this dialog.

> Lor San Tekka: Oh, the General? To me, she is royalty.
>
> Poe Dameron: Yeah, but don't call her Princess, not to her face. She doesn't like it anymore. *Really* doesn't like it.

(Dialog from the novelization)

Now, I'm assuming that she doesn't like it as that is how Han referred to her.

Do we have any indication of when it was decided that 'Princess" was not her formal title any more?

Comment: She refers to herself as one (in an ironic tone) in the novelisation; "*The name of a particular pilot had been put forth. His record was no less than remarkable, and she could hardly argue that **a pilot scouting solo would draw less attention than a perambulating princess.** So she agreed.*"

Comment: Whenever the Lady Vader visits [Honoghr](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Noghri).

Comment: If the title was from her adopted mother's status on Alderran, then I can see why she'd drop it after the planet was obliterated.

Answer (score 6):

Not too long after the Battle of Endor (some time [around 4-5ABY](https://starwarscanontimeline.com/book/aftermath-life-debt/)), she at least indicated to another Alderaanian that she had no desire to use the title anymore.

> *Leia draws back the hood.
>
>   She can’t help but smile. “Evaan Verlaine,” she says.
>
>   “Hello, Last Princess of Alderaan.”
>
>   **“I don’t go by that anymore.”***
>
> <sub><sup>[Aftermath: Life Debt](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aftermath:_Life_Debt)</sup></sub>

However, it appears to generally still be customary and polite for others to still call her 'Princess' (or at least think that she so desires to be called that)

> *"Leia," Jas says.
>
>   "That's **Princess** Leia to you," Norra says.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Aftermath: Life Debt](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aftermath:_Life_Debt)</sup></sub>

Comment: She mostly uses the title as a weapon against those she thinks are being overly formal or (conversely) overly disrespectful.

Comment: Out of universe it may also be an author's choice as well and not necessarily a hard and fast rule (yet, anyway). Meaning, "Bloodline" which is post-Aftermath has heavy use of the "Princess" title and she doesn't appear to correct anyone as she does in 'Life Debt'

Comment: Thanks @Valorum for the actual year edit - I was having trouble finding a good source on that

Comment: I think this is the sort of thing that's too important to be left to individual authors to decide. The fact that it's said to Evaan (from the comic serial) suggests strongly that the Story Group would be likely to have weighed in.